# Sending php array to a javascript function with button onclick in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, bootstrap-modal

Maybe it was a little confusing.

I have a datatable. In this datatable, there is an edit button at the end. Clicking on the edit button opens a modal. I want to pass the data in this datatable to the modal. I can send it as a single variable, but when I want to convert the data to an array and throw it away, I get an error.

My table:

```
<td><input type="text" value="<?= $datt['a']; ?>" id ="a" class="form-control"/> </td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?= $datt['b']; ?>" id ="b" class="form-control"/> </td>
<td><input type="text" value="<?= $datt['c']; ?>" id ="c" class="form-control"/> </td>  
<? $arry = array(
"a" => $datt['a'],
"b" => $datt['b'],
"c" => $datt['c']);  ?>
<td><button id="updd" class="btn btn-success updd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updd" onclick="show_fun(<?= $arr ?>)">Edit</button></td>
```

JS function:

```
function show_fun(datt){
$(document).on("click", ".updd", function (e) {
 var obj = datt;

 console.log(datt);
```

});

Result:

> Array() { [native code] }

I also sent the Array with json_encode.

I tried

```
onclick="show_fun(<?= $arr ?>)"
```

instead of

```
onclick="show_fun(<?= json_encode($arr) ?>)"
```

Result:

> undefined

How can I send data to modal?

Comment: You cannot echo an array. Try using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to properly encode it before echoing it

Comment: well `datt` is undefined. `dat` is defined though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need inner click listener. In HTML:

```
<button ... onclick="show_fun(<?= json_encode($arr); ?>);" />
```

In JS:

```
function show_fun(dat) {
 console.log(dat);
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly the solution. I needed to use htmlspecialchars(json_encode($arr)) instead of json_encode($arr). Thanks.